# Google Maps aerial photography

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, google

I've been playing around with GeoServer, Google Maps and OpenLayers and have been reasonably successful however when using the aerial photography from Google I don't seem to be able to zoom in as far as I should be able to.

Any ideas?

Comment: aerial photography or satellite imagery? - the aerial photos are oblique in locations around the world. Example http://geochalkboard.wordpress.com/2009/12/08/google-maps-adds-oblique-aerial-imagery/

Comment: when using the oblique imagery I believe the map type switches and your zoom control is more limited due to resolution of the imagery

Comment: i was using the G_SATELLITE_MAP option.  Looking at the api docs for google there is an option G_AERIAL_MAP, however whatever position i go to it says it doesnt have aerial photos at this zoom level, however if i go to the same place in google i can zoom right in

Comment: guys think ive worked this out.  Just needed to set the maxzoonlevel.  thanks for the help.  Very new to this so think you will see me alot in the coming days / weeks :)

Answer (score 1):

Google has don't have unique(max) zoom level support for whole world. It differs based on location.

If you are familiar with Google Maps JS API you could do API calls to check the zoom level for the location. Here sample page: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maxzoom-simple.html